# How can I lock a file in a Java IDE to avoid accidental change

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

Say, I am working in a Java EE project which involves several files, I have already completed work in some files and I want to lock them to avoid accidental change. How can I do this in Eclipse or Netbeans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, neither Netbeans nor Eclipse has this feature.

The best practice is to keep them in version control (e.g. git) so that if you change them, it's easy to revert them back to what they should be. There are many other benefits to version control.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you could set the read-only-attribute of the file itself.
(Works at least under Windows with Netbeans).